# Starting a process from servlet doPost()

Tags: java, servlets, runtime.exec

I am calling a external process (git command) from inside of doPost method of my servlet. The post request comes to the servlet via an `xhttpRequest()` call when user clicks on a button.
In my code I am printing out the response HTML using the writer object of the response. And weirdly when the code reaches the process part it executes fine in the background but I don't see the correct response. Does someone has some insights to this problem? I am using `streamgobbler` class as described in this link: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2
Snippet of the process part of the code from the `doPost()` method is below.

```
try {
    String line;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    Process cloneProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git clone " +
                              hvafModifiedXMLRepository + " " +
                              xmlRepoPath.toString());
    StreamGobbler errorGlobber = new StreamGobbler(cloneProcess.getErrorStream(), "CMDTOOL-E",resp.getWriter());
    StreamGobbler outputGlobber = new StreamGobbler(cloneProcess.getInputStream(), "CMDTOOL-O",resp.getWriter());
    errorGlobber.start();
    outputGlobber.start();
    cloneProcess.waitFor();
    if (cloneProcess.exitValue() != 0)
        throw new IOException(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(lines, "\n"));
    System.out.println("Done.");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    sendLogHead(resp);
    sendLog(resp, "Unable to clone Modified XML repository.", ex);
    sendLogTail(resp);
    return;
}
```

Here is my POST request.

```javascript
function sendSelectedTestCasesToServlet(paramData, projName, uniqueInstanceName, configCapabilities) {
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
            document.getElementById('content').parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById('content'));
        document.getElementById('footer').parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById('footer'));
        var el = document.createElement('html');
        el.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        var newBody = document.createElement('div');
        newBody.innerHTML = AJS.$(el.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).html();
        document.body.appendChild(newBody);
        window.stop();
    }
    else if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 404) {
        return;
    } else if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 500) {
        document.getElementById('content').parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById('content'));
        document.getElementById('footer').parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById('footer'));
        var el = document.createElement('html');
        el.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        var newBody = document.createElement('div');
        newBody.innerHTML = AJS.$(el.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).html();
        document.body.appendChild(newBody);
        window.stop();
    }
};var baseurl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + new URI(window.location.href).path()
xhttp.open('POST', baseurl + '?test-cases-for-configs=' + paramData + '&project-name=' + projName + '&job-instance-uniqueId=' + uniqueInstanceName + '&havf-config-capabilities=' + configCapabilities, true);
xhttp.send()
}
```

Comment: @MichałZaborowski: Not really, the process runs of fine actually. Just that servlet sends response back to the browser before the process is actually over despite .waitFor() method being called.

Comment: "servlet sends response back to the browser before the process is actually over despite .waitFor() method being called" - means the process got terminated.

Comment: @Kishore- see the process being working fine(git clone being successful) and print messages on the console.

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: @Kishore: The POST call using xhttpequest to the servlet. Now the code works fine till the git process in invoked. But as soon as it reaches git process part it kind of goes haywire and the browser reloads the same page with the process getting executed fine in the background.

Comment: Maybe the issue is in the js code.

Comment: @Kishore: I do receive a xhttp.status as 0. I have edited my question to put the JS code.

Comment: You mean you get `xhttp.status` as `200`, right? Also, what is the `response` that you expect to receive?

Comment: @Kishore:No I mean '0' only. When I cycle through the response status and ready status, at the end of it the .readyStatus is 4 and .status is 0. expected response is  basically the whole html output which I want browser to render but actual response is blank.

Comment: XHR status of 0 throws some ambiguity in the question. First of all, when you replace the servlet code by just a simple `out.print("hello")` for testing purposes, does it work? If so, then XHR is unlikely the problem. If not, then servlet is unlikely the problem. You should focus the question on one of the sides, not both.

Comment: @BalusC: Well simple print statement work fine. Like I mentioned before that its only when the code comes to the git process part it just reloads the page.